# How to solve Usermanage System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-identity

The code was working perfectly but all of a sudden the seed method for the user is no longer working after I push to the production server with a fresh database.

- `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    })
        .AddErrorDescriber<JapaneseErrorDescriber>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".AdventureWorks.Session";

        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider service)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    ApplicationDbInitializer.SeedUsers(userManager, context);


    app.UseSession();


    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });


}
```

-- Seed method

```
public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@admin.com").Result == null)
    {
        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = "admin@admin.com",
            Email = "admin@admin.com"
        };

        IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "adminpass").Result;

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)'
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
        }
    }

}
```

So I deleted all the data from the Dev Database and tried to see what was going on. In debugging mode, I was getting the instance of the `Usermanger` but when the call to the `CreateAsync()` was called the error occurs.

Comment: Can you post your controller because if you pass dependency into constructor then its wok fine otherwise you'll get error in  userManager object  ref error.  public SecurityController(
             UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
             SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager){ _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;}

Comment: I just copy your code in a new project and run it, the user created without error. please share your GitHub repo to test.

Comment: @SalehBagheri it was working tomorrow upto the last commit but not today. The repo is private. Sorry for the hassle :(